# Can we pass data from controller in one js file into another js file? (angularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am creating a table using javascript. I have one js file in which i have a controller with json data ( the json data consists of width,height,color,etc... ). I have another javascript file in which i created a table.

AngularJS file ( for eg ):

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("data",function($scope){ $scope.details = [{
       "width":"400px", "height":"500px"
    }];
});
```

and this is my js file for table ( for eg ):

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var j=0;j<5;j++){ 
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Now, my question is how can i pass the data of controller from that js file to the table creating js file. Because with that data only, i am setting height, width and many more.

For Example.: table.style.width = $scope.data.width;

Is there any way to pass the data from one js to another js file?

Comment: Yes, you can add attributes to window object. But please keep in mind, page will not reload in this case. Else your window object gets reintialized and you need to assign attribute again. Another way why don't you use service or factory ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style inline an object, you can use your angular controller inside your table without another javascript file.

Besides, if you want it to appear only when you want, you can use an "ng-show" or "ng-if" *(just don't use both of them)*.

Just like this: `<table ng-show="myCondition" style="width: {{table.width}}; height: {{table.height}}; color: {{table.color}}" >`

where ***table*** is your specification object.

Inside your controller it can look like this:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('myTableController',  function($scope){  

     $scope.table = { 
         width: 100px, 
         height: 100px, 
         color: blue 
         /*... Other specifications*/ 
     };

 });
```

Here's a working snippet of what I think you want, its ***very basic*** but goes to the point:

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);


var controller = function($scope){
  
  //initializing our table specification object
  $scope.table = {  
    
    width: '300px',
    height: '50px',
    color: 'blue'  
  };
  
};

app.controller('myCtrl', controller);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">  
  <!-- Here goes your styling! -->
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="show=true">
    <hr>
    <h4>Current table data: </h4>
    {{table}}
    <hr>
  
  Width: <input type="text" ng-model="table.width" placeholder="Input your width here in pixels"/><br><br>
  Height: <input type="text" ng-model="table.height" placeholder="Input your height here in pixels"/><br><br>
  Color: <input type="text" ng-model="table.color" placeholder="Input your color here (eg. black, #ffffff )"/>
    &nbsp;Show? <input type="checkbox" ng-click="show = !show" checked/>
  
  <hr>
  <table ng-if="show" border="1" style="width: {{table.width}}; height: {{table.height}}; color: {{table.color}}">
    <tbody>      
      <tr>
        <td>My Content1</td>
        <td>My Content2</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
        <td>My Content1</td>
        <td>My Content2</td>
      </tr>          
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    
</div>
```